# SSRS Receiving #ERROR when creating running total using lookup function that has occasional null or zero values

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

This is what the error looks like

[image: error]

I'm trying to accomplish is to subtract sales from inventory then add transfers.  When transfers evaluates to zero I am getting the error.

I'm new to SSRS so I have kind of hacked this together so far.  I am pulling data from two datasets using lookup function.  So the Transfers column is an expression calculated like so:

```
=IIF(ISNOTHING(Lookup(Fields!Date.Value, Fields!Date.Value, Fields!QUAN.Value, "DataSet3")),0,Lookup(Fields!Date.Value, Fields!Date.Value, Fields!QUAN.Value, "DataSet3"))
```

Which is working perfectly as I want it to.  Then my running total (resulting inventory) code is:

```
=RunningValue(Fields!Sales_per_day.Value*-1 + (IIF(ISNOTHING(Lookup(Fields!Date.Value, Fields!Date.Value, Fields!QUAN.Value, "DataSet3")),0,Lookup(Fields!Date.Value, Fields!Date.Value, Fields!QUAN.Value, "DataSet3"))), Sum, Nothing) + Parameters!Balance.Value
```

So, essentially, I am recreating the lookup and doing the calculations as if the transfers column doesn't even exist (separate problem perhaps, because I don't know how to refer to the resulting expression from another column).  As soon as I hit a zero value though, boom, #ERROR.

ANy help appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would refer to the resulting expression from another column by using the following method:

first identify the name of the column containing the value from the expression you wish to reference by going into property settings ie "Transfers"

second insert a column and in the expression field type in:
=reportitems!Transfers.Value